# How to validate FormView data when using EnableModelValidation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I'm trying to use `FormView` and want to validate some data in the server side. I'm trying to use the property `EnableModelValidation` but [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.enablemodelvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is very incomplete for this.

I [saw an aproach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2008/06/18/using-asp-net-dynamic-data-with-objectdatasource.aspx) (*but about Dynamic Data instead of just ObjectDataSource*) where you throw a `ValidationException` and it will handle if you have a `ValidationSummary`. Unfortunately it crashes with the yellow error page instead of showing the summary.

Following is my class:

```
namespace FormViewTest
{
    [DataObject]
    public class Person
    {
        private int age;

        [DataObjectField(false)]
        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set
            {
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    throw new ValidationException("Invalid age");
                }
                age = value;
            }
        }

        public void Insert(Person p)
        { }

        public Person Get()
        {
            return new Person();
        }
    }
}
```

and the aspx:

```
<asp:FormView runat="server"
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1"
    DefaultMode="Insert"
    EnableModelValidation="true">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        Age:
        <asp:TextBox ID="AgeTextBox" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Bind("Age") %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server"
            CommandName="Insert"
            Text="Insert" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
    DataObjectTypeName="FormViewTest.Person"
    InsertMethod="Insert" SelectMethod="Get"
    TypeName="FormViewTest.Person"></asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
```

I've tried to add other control as said in the article I mention but it did nothing:

```
<asp:DynamicValidator ErrorMessage="Error" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="ObjectDataSource1"  />
```

I hope someone can help me to use this `EnableModelValidation` since there is no official documentation I could find about it.

Comment: How developed of a project is this? Is moving to MVC an option? It provides exactly what you are after here.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie Sorry for the delay. It's not an option move to MVC because it is a big (very big actually) Web application and I really want to focus in this particular `FormView` feature. Thank's

Comment: I haven't found yet how to properly hookup the functionality you are after. Is this model to be used multiple places (thus the desire for model validation vs something like `<asp:RangeValidator ... />`)? For the quick fix, you can use `RequiredValidator` and `RangeValidator` in the aspx.  I'll see if I can get model validation working myself, or else hopefully someone more knowledgeable comes along.

Comment: @MikeGuthrie Probably I will end up using those validators. As `fnostro` had mention looks like this specific property works only with Dynamic Data and not plain old `ObjectDataSource`. BTW `Guthrie`? Like the ONE? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Enabling that property is not going to do anything unless you are using DynamicData version of  FormView  See [**this**](http://www.meineck.net/2008/06/aspnet-dynamic-data-new-feature-in.html) for a better explanation on using ASP.NET Dynamic Data Scaffolding along with some useful links

Comment: Sorry but the link you provided is mentioned in the one I provided. It didn't help me to achieve what I wanted. But at least you clarify it only work with Dynamic Data.